# Aurelia: Accessing parent VM method from within child VM

Tags: javascript, aurelia

A common use case working with lists is accessing a method of the list from within a list-item. For example: a project-item has an option to delete itself from the containing list. I would like to know if the pattern I describe below for Aurelia is valid or maybe there are better solutions.

In Aurelia I have the following setup:

The containing list: (project-list.html and projectList.js)

```
<template>      
  <div class="projects">
    <input value.bind="newProjectName" placeholder="New project name"/>
    <project-item repeat.for="project of projects" project.bind="project"></project-item>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the child item: (project-item and projectItem.js)

```
<template>
  <span class="title">
    ${project.name} <i click.delegate="deleteProject(project)" class="icon-trash"></i>
  </span>
</template>
```

In this case `deleteProject(project)` is a member of projectList VM:

```
function deleteProject(project){
    var index = this.projects.indexOf(project);
    if (index>-1){
        this.projects.splice(index,1)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as I understand from this issue https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/311,
that wil not work (anymore).

As a work-around I can bind a function on the project-item VM:

```
@bindable delete: Function;
```

and in the project-list template:

```
<project-item repeat.for="project of projects" project.bind="project" delete.bind="deleteProject"></project-item>
```

That does work, provide the bound function is a assigned property with a closure:

```
deleteProject = function(project : Projects.Project){
        var index = this.projects.indexOf(project);
        if (index>-1){
            _.remove(this.projects,(v,i)=>i==index);
        }
    }
```

The closure is needed to acces the correct context (`this` being the project-list). Using

```
function deleteProject(project)
```

`this` would refer to the context of the project-item.

Even though this construction works and has not much overhead in plumbing, it feels to me a bit fragile:

- The assigned function is hard to distinguish form a regular class function
- binding the function as well as the list-item seems a bit "overdone"

Or maybe I'm missing an Aurelia bubbling mechanism that makes accessing a parent VM handled by the framework?

Edit after answer:
Based on the answer by @Sylvain I made a GistRun that implements a skeleton list and list-item implementation with add and remove:

[Aurelia Skeleton list list-item implementation](https://gist.run/?id=498a350f21e7f57459e49fc8a444be52)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few alternatives to passing a reference to the function:

- Have the child component broadcast a public event using the `EventAggregator` singleton instance and have the parent component react to the event
- Have the child component broadcast a private event using a private `EventAggregator` instance and have the parent component react to the event
- Have the child component broadcast a DOM event and bind it to the parent with `delete.call` like this `<project-item repeat.for="project of projects" project.bind="project" delete.call="deleteProject($even t)"></project-item>`

My personal preference is the third option. It feels more like "Web Components" to me.

Comment: I use the third option too. But note that when you have `delete.call="deleteProject(projectParam)"`, you need to call it from `project-item` like `this.delete({projectParam: this.project})`

Comment: The third option using `.call` binding is definitely what is was looking for. I am still struggling with the parameter though. @Sylvain: you use `$event` in your answer. That works and `deleteProject` is called with the project as parameter. Also `delete.call="deleteProject(project)"` results in the correct call. Could you explain what the $event parameter means in this context?

Comment: @valichek: I assumed by "call it from project-item" you mean from within the viewmodel class. I tried your suggestion but i can't get it working. I tried : `function doDelete(){ this.delete(this.project); }` in the `projectItem` class. But `this.delete` is undefined. So I guess that is not what you intended?

Comment: @Arjan Consider you have `@bindable delete` inside projectItem VM, and you have `<project-item repeat.for="project of projects" project.bind="project" delete.call="deleteProject(someParam)"></project-item>` in projectList template, so you call `deleteProject` defined in projectList VM. To get it called you write `this.delete({projectParam: this.project})` in projectItem VM, note you need to pass OBJECT and note that no closures needed, `deleteProject` has to be defined as usual "method"

Comment: @Arjan that is what I mean: https://gist.run/?id=e1243ac2bfad79c7f6ee2dd6b1b68c1f

Comment: @valicheck, I see what you mean. That will be useful in cases when extra info has to be provided for the containing list: like providing reason for removal or moving items up/down in the list.